# Excelのマクロを使っているのですがmenuの中のセルをクリックしてもエクセルのタブがひらけません

Tags: excel

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

Dim i
For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
  ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Range("M" & i), _
  Address:="", _
  SubAddress:=Worksheets(i).Name & "!A1", _
  TextToDisplay:=Worksheets(i).Name
Next

End Sub
```

Excelのマクロ

[image]

Comment: ハイパーリンクのアドレスがどうなっているのかを確認すると原因が分かるのではないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SubbAddress`の行を下記のように書き直してください。

```
'修正前
SubAddress:=Worksheets(i).Name & "!A1", _
'修正後
SubAddress:="'" & Worksheets(i).Name & "'!A1", _
```

シート名が数式などを含む場合には、シート名をシングルクォーテーション(`'`)で囲まないと暗黙の型変換の前に自動計算が発生してしまい、正しくリンクが貼れないようです。

**修正前のコードでは正しく動作しないシート名の例**

- 数式を含む: `0001-1`, `1+23`
- 空白を含む:  `Hoge`, `Fuga` , `1 2`

単純な前ゼロや日本語の文字列は未確認ですが、一律でシングルクォーテーション("'")で囲って文字列として連結するのが無難でしょう。

Comment: 有難うございました。上手くいきました｡ SAYURIさんの方法でマクロを使わず処理出来ればと思ったのですが｡

Comment: @user29507 新たに質問を立てて、実現したいことを具体的に説明してもらえませんか？

Comment: セルに関数　"=HYPERLINK("#'1001'!A1","2学期")" を張り付ける事で解決しました。　有難う御座いました。

Answer (score 0):

やりたいことが正確には読み取れませんが、`A1`セルにシート名が記述されている時、当該シート名にジャンプするハイパーリンクを作成したいということでしょうか？ VBAは不要で通常の数式で実現できます。具体的には

```
=HYPERLINK("#"&ADDRESS(1,1,1,1,A1),A1)
```

という数式で実現できます。

- [`ADDRESS`関数](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/address-%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0-d0c26c0d-3991-446b-8de4-ab46431d4f89)
  引数で指定されたセルを参照する文字列を作成します。
- [`HYPERLINK`関数](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/hyperlink-%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f)
  指定された内容でハイパーリンクを作成します。ドキュメントにはありませんが、先頭に`#`を付けるとブック内リンクとして解釈されるようです。

Comment: HYPERLINK関数を設定しようと試みているのですが =HYPERLINK("#"&ADDRESS(1,1,1,1,A1),A1) 　張り付けても上手くいきません。というより張り付け方がわるいようです。 =HYPERLINK("#"&0001-2) ?  =HYPERLINK("#0001-4!A1","■") でもダメです

Comment: @user29507 ちょっと何を言っているのかわかりませんでした。キーボードやマウスの操作方法が分からないという意味ではありませんよね？  Excelの数式の書き方が分からないということでしょうか？

Comment: Excelの数式の書き方が分からないということです。ADDRESSもそのまの記述ではまずいですよね。NETでHYPERLINKを参照して貼り付けしても反応しません。

Answer (score 0):

テキストから参照先のシートにハイパーリンクをつけるのであれば、
テキストを選択し、挿入→リンク→ハイパーリンクで参照先のシートを選択すればできます。

あとは、メニューのシートと参照先のシートを分割表示すればできませんか？